# What is the difference between *(id *)((char *)object + ivar_getOffset(ivar)) and object_getIvar(object, ivar)

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

According the [Objective-C runtime reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/object_getIvar):

> ivar_getOffset
>   Returns the offset of
>   an instance variable.
>
> ptrdiff_t ivar_getOffset(Ivar ivar)
>   Discussion For instance variables of
>   type id or other object types, call
>   object_getIvar and object_setIvar
>   instead of using this offset to access
>   the instance variable data directly.
>
> Declared In runtime.h

Why is this?  What does object_getIvar do to object types?

EDIT: changed question from subscripting (void *) to (id *).

Comment: Subscripting `void` should cause the compiler to complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between those two approaches when it comes to getting the value of the ivar. You can verify this by looking at `object_getIvar()`'s implementation in Apple's open-source [Obj-C runtime code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.1/runtime/objc-class.m).

`object_setIvar()` does more than just assign to an offset from the object pointer. It is careful to call through to the garbage-collection runtime function `objc_assign_ivar()` to perform the actual assignment.

More magic might be added to either of these functions in future; in general, you should use the highest-level API available at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's not that `object_getIvar` does something different, but that instance variables of type `id` or other object types are commonplace, and that calling `ivar_getOffset` and appending the result to the value of `object` and then casting to the appropriate type is much more cumbersome.

Note that you cannot reliably increment the value of a `void *`, based on the following information from the C99 standard (emphasis mine):

> C99 §6.2.5 (1): (...) Types are partitioned into **object types** (types that fully describe objects), **function types** (types that describe functions), and **incomplete types** (types that describe objects but lack information needed to determine their sizes).
>
> C99 §6.2.5 (19): The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; it is an **incomplete type** that cannot be completed.
>
> C99 §6.5.6 (2): For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a pointer to an **object type** and the other shall have integer type. (Incrementing is equivalent to adding 1.)
>
> C99 §6.5.2.1 (1): One of the expressions shall have type “pointer to **object type**”, the other expression shall have integer type, and the result has type “type”.

To increment a pointer by an arbitrary number, you can use `char *` instead.